# User removed versus reputation cap

Tags: support, reputation

Dutch people are known to be always calculating....

Yesterday, two things happened to me at the same time:

- I hit the daily quote, actually passed it, which "zeroed" the effect of a number of votes. (in total `+280` or something like that)
- A user was removed: `-70`

*If* these things happen at the same time (on the same day), actually the reputation on that day is `+145` (`215`-`70`, `200` + one accepted answer). Shouldn't the additional votes count then?
That is not what happened; even *including* the `-70`, I would have been over `+200`, but it is `+145`.

#### Imagine

Just theoretically: if the 70 points where earned on a day I *also* surpassed the cap, I would possibly lose the same reputation *twice*, which shouldn't be possible in *any* calculation system.

Comment: I guess the same person - I lost 20 and gained 2. Must have been prety active

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You did get 215 points, but the 70 points were subtracted from an earlier date - when the votes were granted. That's to say, it's as if you *started* the day with 70 points less. See [this Meta SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142616/270345). Do check out what https://askubuntu.com/reputation says about your reputation for that day.

Comment: Excellent, very sharp. The rep on the profile page is a bit unclear then. It sais `+145` for yesterday...

Comment: @JacobVlijm to parrot animuson: You might be interested in [Separate and visually indicate reversal events from the day's reputation changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146682/270345). :D

Answer (score 2):

The problem, beside Jacob Vlijm's case, which is a particular case, [actually exists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70158/what-if-i-hit-the-daily-rep-cap-and-then-get-downvoted) (thanks to muru for the link): if you lose reputation after having capped the limit due to other reasons (downvotes or bounties), *the reputation loss is not balanced by the amount of reputation gained over the limit*.

Here's a summary of my reputation variation two days ago (09/02).

"post" view:

[image: screenshot1]

- Had some upvotes between 00:00 and 9:09, which gave me 10 reputation each;
- Had a downvote at 9:09, which gave me -2 reputation;
- Had some upvotes to the point of capping 200 with an upvote at 18.53, which only gave me 2 reputation ("balancing" the downvote at 9:09) (the timestamp reports 19.14 because as explained in the next point I've had two upvotes shortly after which gave me no reputation which were merged into a single entry; so the timestamp of the last one is reported);
- Had 2 upvotes, which gave me no reputation;
- Had a final downvote at 22:57, which gave me -2 reputation, making the daily total 198.

Doing some math, out of a total of 23 upvotes and 2 downvotes I gained a total of 198 reputation because the last vote was a downvote.

"time" view:

[image: screenshot]